# SharePointPro magazine using dotnetnuke?

Tags: 2007

I see a new magazine has launched called [SharePointPro](http://www.sharepointproconnections.com/home.aspx). Are they really using dotnetnuke for their site? ;)

Comment: @orl78: Sorry, I should have caught this earlier... We're looking for questions about SharePoint here, not other sites :-)  Thanks!

Comment: :( . Hey AC commented on my post :)

Answer (score 2):

So what, just because you can - with loads of effort and money - build a site a on a certain technology (SharePoint), it doesn't mean that you should. They picked a platform that is much more fit for their purpose, a wise decision.

Did you know that SharePoint Overflow is not based on SharePoint? Outrageous! :-p

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Pro mag is part of Pention Media which does the Connections conferences (Dev, Windows, Virtualization, SharePoint, Exchange, etc) as well as publish quite a few different magazines, including SHarePoint Pro. The SharePoint folks would love to move to SharePoint, but as a company they are on the DNN platform.

Course I wish it was on SP as well, but I understand the reason it isn't.

Comment: And not forgetting that coprorate policy is only one reason that this situation may occur.  Sometimes SP just is not the appropriate solution.

Comment: Oh yes and welcome aboard AC!

Answer (score 0):

It can be a licencing issue.